# Solving Integro-Differential equations

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I need help solving this equation. Is there a built in function that solves this type of equations? DSolve wouldn't work.

Updated equation:

```
DSolve[D[p[u, t], t]*(1/M + β*(b^2/Kp)) - (b/(3*Kp))*
    D[pa[t], t] + ((2*b^2)/Kp)*(1 - β)*
    Integrate[D[p[u, t], t]*u, {u, 0, 1}] == (1/u)*D[k[u]*u*D[p[u, t], u], u], 
 p[u, 0] = po, p[1, t] = pa[t], p, {u, t}]
```

The error I get is:

Input is not an ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You may receive more and better answers if you include at least the Mathematica code for the equation and perhaps some failed intent to solve it

Comment: Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: @Raven: your equation for p[u,t] is linear (I guess pa'(t) means D[p[u,t],u]/.u->a) and can therefore be solved by standard mathematical methods once you provide the boundary and initial conditions. Physically it decribes Diffusion in a cylinder. A necessary condition can be obtained by differentiating the equation with respect to u. The resulting equation for q = D[p,u] is solved by MMA exactly in terms of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Outline**

As you didn't provide boundary and initial conditions and the function pa'[t] this solution must be generic.

Your equation for p[u,t] is linear (I guess pa'(t) means D[p[u,t],u]/.u->a) and can therefore be solved by standard mathematical methods once you provide the boundary and initial conditions. Physically it describes diffusion in a cylinder. A necessary condition can be obtained by differentiating the equation with respect to u. The resulting equation for q = D[p,u] is solved by *Mathematica* exactly in terms of Bessel functions.

**Derivation**

The integral differential equation in Mathematica terms is (pap is pa'(t))

```
D[p[u, t], t] + Integrate[u D[p[u, t], t], {u, 0, 1}] - pap[t] == (1/
  u) (D[p[u, t], u] + u D[ p[u, t], {u, 2}]) (* equation 1 *)
```

Differentiating the equation with respect to u lets the integral and the term pa'[t] vanish and gives for

```
q[u,t] = D[p[u,t],u]
```

the equation

```
D[q[u, t], t] == D[(1/u D[r q[u, t]]), u] (* equation 2 *)
```

This linear equation can be solved by standard methods. 
In fact separating of variables writing q = T[t] * U[u] gives

```
T'[t]/T[t] = - k^2 = U''[u] + 1/u U'[u] - 1/u^2 U[u]
```

where -k^2 is the separation parameter.
The ODEs for T[t] and U[u] and their respective solutions are

```
solT = DSolve[T'[t] == -k^2 T[t], T[t], t]

(*
Out[246]= {{T[t] -> E^(-k^2 t) C[1]}}
*)

solU = DSolve[U''[u] + 1/u U'[u] - 1/u^2 U[u] == -k^2 U[u], U[u], u]

(*
Out[245]= {{U[u] -> BesselJ[1, k u] C[1] + BesselY[1, k u] C[2]}}
*)
```

The separation parameter must be determined by the boundary conditions of U[u] at some u=u1 and u=u2.

Most frequently u1 = 0 and it is requested that U remains finite. This forces the BesselY term to vanish (which we assume in what follows).
The other condition might be U[u=1] = 0 which leads to discrete values of k, called k[i] here.

The general solution of equation 2 is therefore of the form

```
q[u, t] = Sum[ a[i] Exp[- k[i]^2 t] BesselJ[1, k[i] u], {i, 1, ∞}]
```

where the coefficients a[i] have to be determined by the initial condition q[u,t=0].

Now we turn to the original function p[u,t].

Integrating q[u,t] from u=0 to u gives (notice J[0] instead of J[1], and letting b[i] = a[i]/k[i])

```
p[u, t] = Sum[ 
   b[i] Exp[- k[i]^2 t] BesselJ[0, k[i] u], {i, 1, ∞}] + g[t]
```

where g[t] is an arbitrary function of t alone.

Inserting this solution into equation 1 we have with

```
pk[u_, t_] := Exp[- k[i]^2 t] BesselJ[0, k[i] u]
```

on the one hand

```
(1/u) (D[pk[u, t], u] + u D[ pk[u, t], {u, 2}]) // FullSimplify

(*
Out[256]= -E^(-t k[i]^2) BesselJ[0, u k[i]] k[i]^2
*)

D[pk[u, t], t] // FullSimplify

(*
-E^(-t k[i]^2) BesselJ[0, u k[i]] k[i]^2 + g'[t]
*)
```

Hence we are left with

```
Integrate[u D[p[u, t], t], {u, 0, 1}] - pap[t] == g'[t]
```

The integral can be done giving

```
Integrate[u BesselJ[0, k[i] u], {u, 0, 1}]

(*
Out[251]= BesselJ[1, k[i]]/k[i]
*)
```

and the final equation is then

```
Sum[ b[i]/k[i] Exp[- k[i]^2 t] BesselJ[1, k[i] u], {i, 1, ∞}] +  
  g[t] == g'[t] + pap[t] (* equation 3 *)
```

**Summary**

Apart from the time dependence through the unknown function pap[t], the solution can be expressed by standard functions within Mathematica.

Comment: The function pa[t] is the pressure applied on the surface of the cylinder. p[1,t]=pa[t]. I have also updated my complete equation.

Comment: @Raven: I have described the solution procedure completely in my answer. You should now go through it step by step provide the boundary and initial conditions and the external funtion pf[t]. In the end you'll obtain p[u,t].